# How to setup Drupal Multisite?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I can't setup a drupal multisite on my sever. I don't get errors but I can't show my other site.

I do the following:

- First, Install my Site master Drupal with drush.
- Then, created the master database for my Site Maste Drupal.
- Then, setup installation with the database.
- Then, created a directory named `blogsite` inside of directory `sites/` of my Site Master Drupal.
- Then, created a other database for my second site.
- Then, copy the file `settings.php` of my Site Master Drupal in `blogsite` and change the configuration of my access to the database.

Now, when I access to my Site Master Drupal with: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/masterDrupal`

Display the main site drupal. But, How to access to the other site?

I put in my browser: `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/masterDrupal/blogsite` but i don't get results.

I need that my second site have the url: `http://blog.site.com` and my Master site have the url: `http://site.com` (I assume that only I need get a Domain for my Site Master Drupal and Sub Domain for my second site)

I only use the command prompt, I don't have cPanel or something like this.

The version of Drupal is 7 on LAMP.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this [link](http://drupal.org/node/1114158), especially the section called [Bulk Loop 3](http://drupal.org/node/1114158)

Comment: @2-Stroker Wow!.. Nice, It's work on my localhost!.. I assume that is the same steps on my server. Thanks

Comment: its the same steps which you will have to repeat on your server as well.